# What is the best way to remove parameters in the url like '?'

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

I am working on web project of J2ee.
When I am running my project i get this link 
Link:- blog1_1/title?uname=55
But I want to change the url to make it look neater.

I'm tring to make it look like - 
Link:- blog1_1/title55

have tried to change with form POST action 
but this is not working

Here's the code -

```
<form id="myform<%=uid1%>" method="POST" action="title?<%=uid1%> >    
                    <% out.println(uid1); %>
                    <input type="hidden" name="uname" value="<%=uid1%>" /> 

 <a     onclick="document.getElementById('myform<%=uid1%>').submit();
     return     false;"></a>
               </form>
```

but when I am running this code, all i get is

this link :-blog1_1/title?55

can you please tell me how should I remove the "?" parameters from the url .

I need to get rid of '?'

Comment: Have you considered using apache rules to achieve this instead?

Comment: The ? denotes the start of the request parameters.  Be aware this is not just a cosmetic change.

Comment: action="title?<%=uid1%> - remove the ? here and make it action="title<%=uid1%>

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding all the parameters to action attribute. When you already submitting the form, request object would have everything, which you can access in your servlet/controller

have your code like :

```
<form id="myform<%=uid1%>" method="POST" action="title"/>
<% out.println(uid1); %>
<input type="hidden" name="uname" value="<%=uid1%>" />
```

in your controller / servlet you can use

```
String uname = (String)request.getParameter("uname")
```

Answer (score 0):

Mehandi Hassan that is called query parameter, you can't remove ? from your URL. 
Two ways we can pass input to our methods

- Using query param in case of GET method
- Using body content in case of POST